# ActionDescriptor.ActionParameters in ActionExecutedContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

There is any thing like the `ActionExecutingContext's ActionDescriptor.ActionParameters` property in the `ActionExecutedContext` class?

I need to investigate the action's parameters at this stage(`OnActionExecuted`).

Answer (score 8):

You can get the parameters and the values like so :

```
// Format the parameters based on our requirements: 
StringBuilder parameters = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var p in filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters())
{
     if (filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue(p.ParameterName) != null)
     {
           parameters.AppendFormat("\r\n\t{0}\t\t:{1}", p.ParameterName,
                       filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue(p.ParameterName).AttemptedValue);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the `ActionExecutedContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters()` method? AFAIK there is no such a `ActionDescriptor.ActionParameters` property. Is it because in your code there is a derived class of `ActionDescriptor`?

Comment: GetParameters() may give me key-value pairs of the parameters?

Comment: Hmmm, it can give you parameter name and parameter TYPE (but not parameter value)

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Hi, Then there is any option to get the parameter value?

Comment: Not so easy as far as I know... U can get the Request parameters (something like filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Params), the "FormCollection" in case of an Post Action (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Form), but they're not binded ! Maybe look at this if it can help. Or be more precise on what you need, there's maybe a better way to achieve it ?

Answer (score -1):

you can get value in OnActionExecuting method:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{    
  var parameters = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters();
  if (parameters.Length >= 1)
  {
    var p = parameters[0];
    var val = filterContext.ActionParameters[p.ParameterName];
    Type type = p.ParameterType;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can then store the parameters under `filterContext.HttpContext.Items` (request-scoped associative array), or in some other request-scoped object using dependency injection.